# Sort the y-axis bars using geom_linerange

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have the following data. I am trying to make a grant chart. In the example, I only put 4 id's but in the original, I have around 30 unique ids.

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(14365, 14914, 14214, 
15400, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957), class = "Date"), treated = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), end_date = structure(c(17896, 17896, 17896, 
17896, 14364, 14913, 14213, 15399), class = "Date"), id = c("A", 
"B", "D", "G", "A", "B", "D", "G")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I am using the following code to plot it.

```
ggplot(df_input) +
  geom_linerange(aes(y = id, 
                     xmin = start_date,
                     xmax = end_date,
                     colour = as.factor(treated)),
                 size = I(5))
```

I am not able to sort y-bars alphabetically, I tried sorting it before plotting but no success. From top to bottom I want A, then B and so on. Also, how can I reduce the gap to 0 between where the bar start which is 2000 and the y-labels A, B, D and G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the order of the y values by using factors - I've done this in the call to ggplot but it couuld be done in the data frame.

Manage the padding around the data with the `expand` argument of the axis scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)


df_input <- structure(list(start_date = structure(c(14365, 14914, 14214, 
                                        15400, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957), class = "Date"), treated = c(1, 
                                                                                                         1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), end_date = structure(c(17896, 17896, 17896, 
                                                                                                                                                      17896, 14364, 14913, 14213, 15399), class = "Date"), id = c("A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "B", "D", "G", "A", "B", "D", "G")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))


ggplot(df_input) +
  geom_linerange(aes(y = fct_rev(id),
                     xmin = start_date,
                     xmax = end_date,
                     colour = as.factor(treated)),
                 size = I(5))+
  scale_x_date(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>